# Wh-question about the future

Tags: future-tense, wh-questions

So I have a question in my book:

> When will the meeting take place?

Can I say the following instead?

> When is the meeting?

We are talking about timetable kind of thing, aren't we?

Comment: There are at least four ways to combine when and the time when a meeting occurs. Maybe more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When is the meeting" is fine (in fact I think it is better).

"When will the meeting be?" works too.